# How can I link back end and front end with Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need help to link the back end of my application and the front end, to create a simple application which would return Working if backend is connected to front end. Besides, when I execute without using Docker, works properly, but when I try with Docker, it didnt connect.

Technologies used:

- Springboot (Backend)
- NodeJs - Express -Axios (Frontend)

Dockerfile, frontend

> ```
> FROM node:14
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY package*.json /app/
>
> RUN npm install -g nodemon
>
> COPY . /app
>
> EXPOSE 3000
>
> CMD ["node", "start"]
> ```

Dockerfile Back-End:

> ```
> FROM openjdk:latest
>
> WORKDIR /usr/src/app
>
> ADD target/springboot.jar /usr/src/app/springboot.jar
>
> EXPOSE 8080
>
> ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/usr/src/app/springboot.jar" ]
> ```

docker-compose.yml code:

> ```
> version: '3.7'
> services:
>     
>     backend:
>         build: 
>             context: backend
>             dockerfile: Dockerfile
>         ports: 
>             - "8080:8080"
>         networks: 
>             - integration
>         
>
>     frontend:
>         build: 
>             context: frontend
>             dockerfile: Dockerfile
>         command: nodemon start frontend/app.js
>         volumes: 
>             - "./frontend:/app/"
>         depends_on: 
>             - backend
>         ports: 
>             - "3000:3000"
>         networks:
>             - integration
>
> networks: 
>     integration:
>         driver: bridge
> ```

Comment: NodeJS is not very accurate. React? Some NodeJS cli app? Details please

Comment: Do absolutely nothing.  (Maybe even delete the `networks:` blocks.)  One container can call the other using the container name as a host name; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  This assumes the `frontend` container is a Node/Express app, and not something that serves an application that ultimately runs in the browser.

Comment: Oh... It's a simple express aplication

Comment: If your frontend code calls the backend api at `localhost:8080` from within your container. The api call actually hits the `localhost:8080`of the frontend container instead of consuming from the backend container. Instead of the local host the IP address of the host machine or the container name  should be specified for making the api calls.

Comment: you don't need the network blocks. if you had two compose setups with the same network definition then they could talk to each other by that connection, but you don't.

Comment: I've tested both jar and js files without Docker, it works, but I cant make it with Docker and I trying to figure out: why?

Comment: Actually I fogot to mention. The application use Axios to get the confirmation of backend as a flag to return: working in the front end application.

Answer (score 0):

Exposed ports are available to other containers at [service]:[port] in this case
backend:8080